# How to prompt user for a file location, search specific files and prompt user if they want to move files

Tags: python

First, I have zero experience in python and have maybe a month's worth of training in Java. I need to write a script that when run will ask the user for a folder path. Upon receiving the path it will search for 3 specific file types, Obliq, pmi, and par. Once it completes the search it should list out the results and ask the user they wish to move to a predetermined folder on the server. If the user types Y all Obliq, pmi, and par files are then relocated.

I've tried os.remove and shutil.move with no success.

```
import os
import shutil

path = image folder
good_size = 86589468
destination = delete folder

bad = set()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):

    for file in files:

        full_file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
        base, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        ext = ext.lower()

        if "Obliq" in base:
            bad.add(full_file_path)
        elif ext == ".pmi":
            bad.add(full_file_path)
        elif ext == ".par":
            bad.add(full_file_path)
if bad:
    print("Badness:")
    print(bad)
    move_files = raw_input('Would you like to move these image(s) to the 
for delete folder? (Y/N)')
    if move_files in ['Y', 'y', 'Yes', 'yes', 'YES']:
        shutil.move(bad, destination)
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question/error/..?

Comment: sorry, stepped away and forgot to ask. This code isn't working. How can I successfully search for these file types, list them for the user and prompt the user whether or not to move the files and move based on Y/N

Comment: Can you please specify what error you are getting?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\alpha\apps\Photogrammetric\!Development\IMH\validate auto-copy.py", line 33, in <module>
    shutil.move(bad, destination)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6\lib\shutil.py", line 298, in move
    if _samefile(src, dst):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6\lib\shutil.py", line 77, in _samefile
    return (os.path.normcase(os.path.abspath(src)) ==
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.6\lib\ntpath.py", line 488, in abspath
    path = _getfullpathname(path)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, set found

Comment: Can you tell me where the error occurs? In which line, it's impossible to tell with the traceback as we do not have the full code with line numbers.

Comment: that's what is so strange. I posted the full code. the error has to be the last line. shutil.move as i successfully make it to the prompt about moving the files. once i hit Y and enter, it returns the error

Comment: it shouldn't be looking at .py files at all. I don't get why it's listed in the error

Comment: @Samuel Rizzo should be correct, you are handing shutil `bad` which is a Set() instead of a string.

Answer (score 1):

"bad" is a set of paths while shutil.move expects a single path as an argument. Just move each file individually:

```
import os
import shutil

path = "image folder"
good_size = 86589468
destination = "delete folder"

bad = set()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):

    for file in files:

        full_file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
        base, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        ext = ext.lower()

        if "Obliq" in base:
            bad.add(full_file_path)
        elif ext == ".pmi":
            bad.add(full_file_path)
        elif ext == ".par":
            bad.add(full_file_path)
if bad:
    print("Badness:")
    print(bad)
    move_files = raw_input('Would you like to move these image(s) to the for delete folder? (Y/N)')
    if move_files in ['Y', 'y', 'Yes', 'yes', 'YES']:
        for bad_file in bad:
            shutil.move(bad_file, destination)
```

Comment: Ah, that worked. I see what I was missing. Thanks for the help. such a simple fix